# How to change the width of box in react-google-charts table?

Tags: charts, google-visualization, react-google-charts

Now, I have created table using  - https://react-google-charts.com/table-chart#simple-example.
But I am unable to change the width of box using react.
I have found the documentation of Bar-format using JavaScript  - https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#barformat

Could anyone please help me to solve this ?

```js
export default class App4 extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={"todo-item2"}>
                <Chart
                    width={'500px'}
                    height={'300px'}
                    chartType="Table"
                    loader={<div>Loading Chart</div>}
                    data={[
                        [
                            { type: 'string', label: 'DATE' },
                            { type: 'string', label: 'GAME - 1' },
                            { type: 'string', label: 'GAME - 2' },
                            { type: 'string', label: 'GAME - 3' },
                        ],
                        ['2020-04-01', 'Team A (Home) vs Team B (Visitor)', 'Team C (Home) vs Team D (Visitor)', 'Team E (Home) vs Team F (Visitor)'],
                        ['2020-04-02', 'Team F (Home) vs Team A (Visitor)', 'Team D (Home) vs Team C (Visitor)', 'Team F (Home) vs Team B (Visitor)'],
                        ['2020-04-03', 'Team B (Home) vs Team A (Visitor)', 'Team C (Home) vs Team D (Visitor)', 'Team F (Home) vs Team E (Visitor)'],
                    ]}
                    options={{
                        showRowNumber: false,
                        width: '10000px', 
                        //height: '500px',
                        
                    }}

                    rootProps={{ 'data-testid': '1' }}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App4 />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

[Please see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDVIH.png)

Comment: will you please share the code used to create table with bar format?

Comment: Sorry , the problem is not a  bar format. I am facing problem to change the width of box in table. Also attached the code and image to understand the problem.

Comment: For example, according to image, Game-1 column shows the data in two lines but I want make it one line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the following config options to change the width,
or any other style of the table cells.

first, we must include...

```
allowHtml: true
```

next, we assign a css class name to the table cells...

```
cssClassNames: {
  tableCell: 'game-cell'
}
```

e.g.

```
options={{
  allowHtml: true,
  cssClassNames: {
    tableCell: 'game-cell'
  },
  showRowNumber: false,
}}
```

then we add the css class to the page somewhere,
either in a `<style>` tag, or in a separate css file using the `<link>` tag

```
.game-cell {
  width: 400px;
}
```

if you want to assign a specific width to the cells, use the above css.

if you want to prevent wrapping to two lines, use the following...

```
.game-cell {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```